# How i can show the entered number in next page on android studio. Just look at the pictures it may help to understand me

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oenxl.jpg)

I want to know how i can show the entered number in next page on both places as shown in the picture.

Comment: send data by intent putExtra

Answer (score 0):

On the first screen :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("phone_number", s);
startActivity(intent);
```

On the second screen :

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity
{
    private String mPhoneNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            mPhoneNumber = extras.getString("phone_number");

            // then, use mPhoneNumber wherever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : better to create a static string for key name